# How to run MySQL script file remotely via ssh?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ubuntu, ssh

I'd like to do something like this:

```
ssh root@host "mysql database -e 'query to run on table_name; more queries to run;'"
```

However, I'd like to run an entire .sql file not just few statements. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the SQL file is on the remote host, put redirection in the remote command:

```
ssh root@host "mysql database < filename.sql"
```

If it's on the local host, redirect the input of SSH:

```
ssh root@host "mysql database" < filename.sql
```

Comment: After I do that I receive a message from the server that includes "Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]" and a very long list of options.

Comment: the second one. It's not an error, rather a guide on flags and options.

Comment: It's an error, it thinks you gave it an incorrect option.

Comment: What does `ssh root@host "type mysql"` say?

Comment: mysql is /usr/bin/mysql

Comment: That's the full statment: ssh root@host "mysql -u root password ***** my_db_name" < backup.sql

Comment: It should be `-p*****` or `--password=******`

Comment: It might be better to put the username and password in `~root/.my.cnf` so you don't have to hard-code it into the script.

Comment: Will do! now it says: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. Does this mean that sql is being executed ?

Comment: Yes. That's just a warning, it's executing the code anyway.

Comment: You can get rid of that by putting the password in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Establish a ssh connection followed by the following command:
`mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME < scripts.sql`
The script should be stored in `scripts.sql` file located at your working directory

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you should upload this .sql file to the remove server before...
You can use `scp` to do that (if you can connect with `ssh`, you can use `scp` too)